# Jenkins Global environment variables in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How do I invoke Global environment variables in Jenkinsfile?
For example, if I have a variable -

```
 name:credentialsId 
 value:xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx
```

How do I use it in the groovy script?

I tried `${credentialsId}`, but it didn't work. It will just give error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, ........
```

Answer (score 49):

In a Jenkinsfile, you have the "[Working with the Environment](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#working-with-the-environment)" which mentions:

> The full list of environment variables accessible from within Jenkins Pipeline is documented at localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env,

The syntax is `${env.xxx}` as in:

```
node {
    echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
}
```

See also "[Managing the Environment](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#managing-the-environment)".

> How can I pass the Global variables to the Jenkinsfile?
> When I say Global variables - I mean in

```
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables
```

See "[Setting environment variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#working-with-the-environment)"

> Setting an environment variable within a Jenkins Pipeline can be done with the `withEnv` step, which allows overriding specified environment variables for a given block of Pipeline Script, for example:
>
> Jenkinsfile (Pipeline Script)

```
node {
    /* .. snip .. */
    withEnv(["NAME=value"]) {
        ... your job
    }
}
```

---

> What's the syntax for `withEnv` if I need to initialize the env variable with another env variable?

If you want to initialize an environment variable with the value of another environment variable in a Jenkinsfile, you can use the `env` object to reference the existing variable.
Here is an example:

```
node {
    withEnv(["NEW_VAR=${env.OLD_VAR}"]) {
        echo "New variable: ${env.NEW_VAR}"
    }
}
```

In this example, `NEW_VAR` is a new environment variable that gets its value from `OLD_VAR`, an existing environment variable.
The `echo` step then prints the value of `NEW_VAR` to the console.

Comment: What's the syntax for withEnv if I need to init env variable with another env variable?

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli I have edited the answer to address your comment. Let me know if I have interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

For getting values all env.VAR, env['VAR'], env.getProperty('VAR') are fine.
For setting values the only safe way at the moment is *withEnv*. If you try to assign values to env.VAR it may not work in some cases like for parallel pipelines (like in [JENKINS-59871](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59871)).

Comment: Alexander, thanks for reporting this. I was trying to debug this exact same issue for a while now. weird that no comment on this issue since you raised it.

Answer (score 3):

When referring to env in Groovy scope, simply use env.VARIABLE_NAME, for example to pass on BUILD_NUMBER of upstream job to a triggered job:

```
stage ('Starting job') {
    build job: 'TriggerTest', parameters: [
        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'upstream_build_number', value: env.BUILD_NUMBER]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Scripted pipeline
To read an environment variable whose name you know, use `env.NAME`

To read an environment variable whose name is not known until runtime use `env.getProperty(name)`.

For example, a value from a YAML config file represents an environment variable name:

**config.yaml** (in workspace)

```
myconfig:
  key: JOB_DISPLAY_URL
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
    println("Running job ${env.JOB_NAME}")
    def config = readYaml(file:'config.yaml')
    def value = env.getProperty(config.myconfig.key)
    println("Value of property ${config.myconfig.key} is ${value}")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Another syntax is $ENV:xxxx

```
node {
echo "Running $ENV.BUILD_ID on $ENV.JENKINS_URL" }
```

This worked for me

Comment: it is somehow similar to the suggestion from VonC.

Comment: This worked for me that's why I suggested this way also although both are almost same just syntax difference

Comment: But I want to define my own Global environment variable in Jenkins instead of define it in my Jenkinsfile.

Comment: in configure jenkins -> Global Properties-> Enviornment Variables are there, So you can try that