# Jenkins Shared Library - Environment Variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I want to have common environment variables through all my pipelines. I am using a Shared Library, so I was wondering, how can I put constant values into a shared library and use it in any pipeline.

Is there a way to put it in the `src` directory, or `vars`, and use it in a pipeline without creating an object in a pipeline?  I tried both but was unsuccessful.

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: As I read the last few lines of the documentation allows you to create global variables, e.g. Fields
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables  
I wonder if it's better to have a static shared step that returns a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

To use global values in your jenkins pipelines, you can makes use of global envs or configuration files in `/resources`

### Global Environment Variables

These are configured on a jenkins level, and can be accessed from any pipeline on the instance (regardless of the use of a shared library)

This is answered in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41235654/22666765

### Shared Library Configuration

A config file can be added (of any format) to the /resources folder in your shared library.
This can then be read using the `libraryResource` function provided by Jenkins https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library

Once the file is read, your values can be parsed & loaded into variables on the pipeline level